# Stop setTimeout animation on hover out

Tags: jquery, hover, css-transitions

So I've got this animation going on on hover:

```
div {
    background: #333333;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}

div span {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333333;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

div span.in {
    opacity: 1;
}

div span.out {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('div').hover(function() {

        var delay_time = 0;

        $(this).find('span').each(function() {

            delay_time += 400;
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#' + id).removeClass('out').addClass('in');
            }, delay_time);

        });

    }, function() {
        $('div span').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kssshhh/qs8bn1ua/

But as soon as you hover across it multiple times, weird stuff happens.

I want it so, that when you hover out, all the spans disappear at the same time.

I've tried to add .stop() on the hover out, but that doesnt seem to do anything.

Does someone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: the timeout is the problem, you need clearTimeout() at appropriate place

Comment: Somehow that didnt work either, i fixed it now doing this instead of the setTimeout:
`$('#' + id).delay(delay_time).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('in');
   });`

and added this on hover out:
`.stop(true,true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up doing this:

```
$(function() {

    $('div').hover(function() {

            var time = 0;

            $(this).find('span').each(function() {

                time += 400;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                $('#' + id).delay(time).queue(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('in');
                });

            });

        }, function() {
            $('div span').finish().removeClass('in').addClass('out');
        });

});
```

I had to use finish() instead of stop(true) or clearqueue(), which both didnt seem to clear the queue properly.

Patricks answer is pretty neat as well though..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your solution.

```
$(function() {
    function animate(id, run, delay_time){
        if(run){
            var tm = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#' + id).removeClass('out').addClass('in');

                }, delay_time);
        }
        else clearTimeout(tm);
    }
   $('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('span').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        animate(id, true, 400);
    });

 }, function() {
      $('div span').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
      animate('', false, 0);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go this will do what your asking. To change the animation just change the css animation. This will time the request right at the moment the browser is doing its repaint. it then has a time delay to let the browser handle anything else it needs to do. also if you hover out in the middle of the animation it will change back to count zero and start to change them to the next set value as needed.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>example</title>
    <style>
        span[display=true]{
             /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-animation-name: showMenu;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /* Standard syntax */
            animation-name: showMenu;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-play-state: running;

        }

        span[display=false]{
             /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-animation-name: hideMenu;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /* Standard syntax */
            animation-name: hideMenu;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-play-state: running;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes showMenu {
            0% {}
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        @keyframes showMenu {
            0% {}
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes hideMenu {
            0% {}
            100% {
                opacity: 0.01;
            }
        }
        @keyframes hideMenu {
            0% {}
            100% {
                opacity: 0.01;
            }
        }


        div {
            background: #333333;
            padding: 40px 20px;
        }

        span {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #333333;
            opacity: 0;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <span display="false">lorem</span>
            <span display="false">ipsum</span>
            <span display="false">dolor</span>
            <span display="false">sit</span>
        </div>


    <script>
        var frames=0;
        var delay = 50;
        var count=0;
        var state="hide";
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
            document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
                count=0;
                state="show";
            });

            document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
                count=0;
                state="hide";

            });
            function loop(){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(count<elements.length){
                        if((frames%delay)==1){
                            switch(state){
                                case "show":
                                    elements[count].setAttribute("display","true");
                                break;
                                case "hide":
                                    elements[count].setAttribute("display","false");
                                break;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    frames++;
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                }, 5);
            }
            loop();
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if you want the mouse out to make it hide all of them at once just change the mouseout to this.

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
    for(var x=0;x<elements.length;x++){
        elements[x].setAttribute("display","false");
    }
    state="hide";
});
```